# How do I filter something in pandas to so that it outputs the first and last date time for every status stage a product is in?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
|Product | Status  | Start_Date |  End_Date |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Apple   | Good    | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------| 
|Apple   | Good    | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------| 
|Apple   | Good    | 2002-01-01 | 2023-09-28|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------| 
|Banana  | Bad     | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2002-01-01 | NaT       |
```

I want to implement a groupby function that outputs the product and the earliest start date and last end date, even if it's a NaT.

I tried this code and it kind of works but it misses the NaT value for Banana.

```
result_df = df.groupby(["Product", "Status"]).agg({"Start_Date": "min", "End_Date": "last"}).reset_index()
```

Ultimately, what I'm looking for is an output like this:

```
For Apple:
|Product | Status  | Start_Date |  End_Date |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Apple   | Good    | 2000-01-01 | 2023-09-23|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|


for banana:
|Product | Status  | Start_Date |  End_Date |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Bad     | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2002-01-01 | NaT       |
```

If Apple had the NaT, I'd also want to be able to output that on a single line/row:

```
|Product | Status  | Start_Date |  End_Date |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Apple   | Good    | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------| 
|Apple   | Good    | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------| 
|Apple   | Good    | 2002-01-01 | NaT       |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------| 
|Banana  | Bad     | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2002-01-01 | NaT       |
```

Intended output:

```
For Apple:
|Product | Status  | Start_Date |  End_Date |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Apple   | Good    | 2000-01-01 | NaT       |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|

for banana:
|Product | Status  | Start_Date |  End_Date |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Bad     | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2002-01-01 | NaT       |
```

But what I get is:

```
|Product | Status  | Start_Date |  End_Date |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Apple   | Good    | 2000-01-01 | 2001-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Apple   | Good    | 2002-01-01 | NaT       |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|

for banana:
|Product | Status  | Start_Date |  End_Date |
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Bad     | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31|
|--------|---------|------------|-----------|
|Banana  | Good    | 2002-01-01 | NaT       |
```

The banana output is correct, not the apple. Is it possible to get the desired output?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With the new example I don't understand the logic there... `Banana` has `NaT` and in the output are `3` rows, but `Apple` only `1` row. Why is the row `Apple  Good  2000-01-01  2000-12-31` missing?

Comment: It's the problem that I'm encountering. If I change the last End_Time for Apple to NaT, then I get two responses for apple when I want the one in the question. I'll edit the question again.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have in the output `Banana   Good 2000-01-01 2000-12-31` and `Banana   Good 2002-01-01        NaT` because the intervals don't intersect? If yes, then this is other type of question...

Comment: No? I re-worded the question again. Hopefully it'd clearer! The Banana output is fine, just not the Apple when Apple ends with a NaT

Comment: Ok, the `Banana` output is fine, because `Banana   Good 2000-01-01 2000-12-31` and `Banana   Good 2002-01-01        NaT` don't intersect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to insert one more condition to `.groupby`:

```py
df = (
    df.groupby(["Product", "Status", df["End_Date"].isna().values])
    .agg({"Start_Date": "min", "End_Date": "last"})
    .droplevel(2)
    .reset_index()
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Product Status Start_Date   End_Date
0   Apple   Good 2000-01-01 2023-09-28
1  Banana    Bad 2001-01-01 2001-12-31
2  Banana   Good 2000-01-01 2000-12-31
3  Banana   Good 2002-01-01        NaT
```

---

EDIT: If you want to merge overlapping intervals:

```py
def group_func(g):
    g["End_Date"] = g["End_Date"].fillna(pd.Timestamp("2199-01-01"))

    g2 = (g["Start_Date"] > (g["End_Date"] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).shift()).cumsum()
    out = g.groupby(g2).agg({"Start_Date": "min", "End_Date": "last"})

    out["End_Date"] = out["End_Date"].replace(pd.Timestamp("2199-01-01"), pd.NaT)
    return out


df = df.groupby(["Product", "Status"]).apply(group_func).droplevel(2).reset_index()
```

Prints:

```
  Product Status Start_Date   End_Date
0   Apple   Good 2000-01-01        NaT
1  Banana    Bad 2001-01-01 2001-12-31
2  Banana   Good 2000-01-01 2000-12-31
3  Banana   Good 2002-01-01        NaT
```

Comment: so it worked and it didn't. If the Apple entries, which had all the same status, ended with a NaT instead of 2023-09-23, I'd get the following output:

Comment: @PRuss Please edit your question and put there example that didn't worked (+ expected output).

Comment: So it worked and didn't work. It gives the right output for Banana but Apple had a NaT, then I'd get two answers.

eg. "Apple   Good 2000-01-01 2001-12-31" and "Apple   Good 2002-01-01 NaT"

is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @PRuss And what should be the answer in this case? As I stated, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77197934/edit) your question and put the input data + expected answer there.

Comment: @PRuss I've updated my answer with edit, how you can merge overlapping intervals.

Comment: Thank you! When I filter df for "Apple" after printing it, I get:

Apple Good 2000-01-01 2000-12-31
Apple Good 2002-01-01        NaT 

instead of: 

Apple Good 2000-01-01 NaT

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the groupby and aggregation functions in pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])
def earliest_start_and_latest_end(series):
    earliest_start = series.min()
    latest_end = series.max()
    return earliest_start, latest_end
result = df.groupby(['Product', 'Status'])['Start_Date', 'End_Date'].agg(earliest_start_and_latest_end)
result = result.reset_index()
```

print(result)